# Elasticsearch - Search and filter by price

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some array with promocodes (comes from request):

```
$promocodes = ['K1H5E1F1', 'M4C8A5K6', 'A3B9A45KL'];
```

And I have products data in Elasticsearch (as example, I will give data of one product):

```
// First product (2 promocodes matched, take a lower price 265.5 and filter this product at this price)
"price": 199,
"promocodes" : [
    {
      "code" : "K1H5E1F1",
      "price" : 265.5
    },
    {
      "code" : "LKDS3534K",
      "price" : 357
    },
    {
      "code" : "A3B9A45KL",
      "price" : 327.5
    }
]

// Second product (1 promocode matched, take a price 700 and filter this product at this price)
"price": 800,
"promocodes" : [
    {
      "code" : "AJ543HJB",
      "price" : 500
    },
    {
      "code" : "M4C8A5K6",
      "price" : 700
    }
]

// Third product (0 promocode matched, take a base price 900 and filter this product at this price)
"price": 900,
"promocodes" : [
    {
      "code" : "AJ87HJ90",
      "price" : 750
    }
]
```

I need to filter products data by price based on promocodes. If you set a range for the price and have promocodes, then you need to filter the products. If the product has the same promocode, then you need to take the price for this promotional code, not the main price. If 2 promocodes match for one product, then you need to take a lower price. In my example, the same product has 2 promotional codes for one product, I need to take the lower price out of 2 prices for the promocode and filter for that particular price.

This request does not filter prices as I need:

```
GET dev_products/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 100,
              "lte": 350
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "promocodes",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "promocodes.code": [
                  'K1H5E1F1',
                  'M4C8A5K6',
                  'A3B9A45KL'
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how to make a request correctly, I ask you for help.

Comment: Maybe someone has at least some ideas with the help of which this can be done?
I will be glad of any help, since I really need to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [inner hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "price": {
              "gte": 100,
              "lte": 350
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "promocodes",
            "query": {
              "terms": {
                "promocodes.code": [
                  "K1H5E1F1",
                  "A3B9A45KL"
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "sort": {"promocodes.price": "asc"},----> sort nested document by price
              "size": 1  ---> return top 1 document
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
 "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index4",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "NTBFgm0BFLPFo7KPt70j",
        "_score" : 2.0,
        "_source" : {
          "price" : 199,
          "promocodes" : [
            {
              "code" : "K1H5E1F1",
              "price" : 265.5
            },
            {
              "code" : "LKDS3534K",
              "price" : 357
            },
            {
              "code" : "A3B9A45KL",
              "price" : 327.5
            }
          ]
        },
        "inner_hits" : {          -----> inner hits contains nested data
          "promocodes" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : null,
              "hits" : [       -----> returns one matched field
                {
                  "_index" : "index4",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "NTBFgm0BFLPFo7KPt70j",
                  "_nested" : {
                    "field" : "promocodes",
                    "offset" : 0
                  },
                  "_score" : null,
                  "_source" : {
                    "code" : "K1H5E1F1",
                    "price" : 265.5
                  },
                  "sort" : [
                    265.5
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

EDIT:
Below logic checks if promocode has match then return document with promocode value in innerhits. If promocode has no match and parent price is in range(gte and lte value) then return that document.

```
GET dev_products/_search
{
  "_source": "price", 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "price": {
                    "gte": 100,
                    "lte": 350
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "promocodes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "promocodes.code.keyword": [
                              "K1H5E1F1",
                              "A3B9A45KL"
                            ]
                          }
                        }

                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "sort": {
                      "promocodes.price": "asc"
                    },
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "promocodes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "promocodes.code.keyword": [
                        "K1H5E1F1",
                        "A3B9A45KL"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "promocodes.price": {
                        "gte": 100,
                        "lte": 350
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "sort": {
                "promocodes.price": "asc"
              },
              "size": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT-2
Query

```
GET dev_products/_search
{
  "_source": "price",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "price": {
                    "gte": 100,
                    "lte": 350
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "must_not": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "promocodes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "promocodes.code.keyword": [
                               "K1H5E1F1",
                               "A3B9A45KL"
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "promocodes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "promocodes.code.keyword": [
                               "K1H5E1F1",
                               "A3B9A45KL"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "promocodes.price": {
                              "lte": 350,
                              "gte": 100
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "inner_hits": {
                    "sort": {
                      "promocodes.price": "asc"
                    },
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
----> don't include document if any matched promcode has value less than given range
            "must_not": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "promocodes",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "terms": {
                            "promocodes.code.keyword": [
                               "K1H5E1F1",
                              "A3B9A45KL"
                            ]
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "range": {
                            "promocodes.price": {
                              "lt": 100
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This request does not execute correctly. He only selects the desired price according to the promocode, but he does not take this price into account in range.
If you set the price range from 100 to 250, then it should filter by this price `265.5`.

Comment: It is necessary to somehow substitute this price `265.5` in price range.

Comment: you want "range": { 
            "price": {
              "gte": 100,
              "lte": 350
            }
          } to apply on promocode.price or outer price ? and this query gives me 265 as answer, you need to check in innerhits section. Document will have both hits and innerhits. Hits will contain entire document all propocode and innerhits will have filtered out data

Comment: And if the product has not matched a single promotional code, then it should filter at the main price (price in field `price`).

Comment: I have added the new query in Edit (answer) does that work for you

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still doesn't work as I need.
At your request: if the product has `promocodes.code`: `K1H5E1F1` and `promocodes.price:` `400`, then it should not fall into the selection (since 400 is more than 350), but it is selected according to your request .

Comment: There is a condition that if no match in promocode then filter should be on parent price. This cannot be handled in elastic search as we will only know data is there or not when search result is returned. So what can be done we can return both documents where either parent price is in certain range or promocode price is in range and pick the price in client side depending on inner hits. If inner hits are returned then take that price else take parent price

Comment: I understand your idea, but the option you proposed does not fit, since it will work for a long time, and my goal is to speed up the search on the site. In fact, my query is much larger and includes many aggregations, and my query returns statistics for a faceted search on the site, and in this case the returned statistics will be incorrect.

Comment: I have updated edit query, can you check if this works

Comment: It looks like your last variant is working correctly, but I will still test it more and then write to you.

Comment: I didn’t find any flaws, everything seems to work well. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: glad could be of help

Comment: Unfortunately, I still found an error and the request does not work correctly. I created a post below and explained in it what exactly does not work.

Comment: So if promocode array contains a queried promocode value but its  price is not in range then query “should not” look for parent prices. Parent price is to be checked only when no matching promocode is there. Am I getting it right?

Comment: Yes, you understood correctly, the price of the promocode is always less than the main price.

Comment: If the product has a promocode, then it should search only at the price for this promocode, and should not pay attention to the parent price.

Comment: Remove range query in must not clause, then check will only be on promo code value and not price range

Comment: This helped in this situation.
After more thorough testing, I will write to you here. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I had a new problem after testing. I updated my post below and described the problem.

Comment: Problem is in second `nested query`: it selects only those promocodes that match the condition of range diapason (`270-271`), and not all that the product has in the conditions of terms.

Comment: I have added EDIT-2 Query for above condition . If you will look at the query it is mostly combination of must and mustnot to check if it should contain certain documents or not

Comment: After EDIT-2 Query doesn't work, doesn't select any documents at all now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200285/discussion-between-jaspreet-chahal-and-brandsley).

Answer (score 0):

If the range for `price` and `promocodes.price` is equal to `"gte":270,"lte":271` and in terms of `promocodes.code` is equal to `["promo1","promo2","promo4"]` the request does not work - in fact, he should not choose this product, since the price according to the lowest promotional code is `265.5` and does not fall into the diapason of range, but he still selects this product and does not add the desired Promocode for `inner_hits` (for some reason he chooses `"promo2"` for `inner_hits` with price `270`).

```
"price": 275,
"promocodes" : [
        {
          "code" : "promo1",
          "price" : 265.5
        },
        {
          "code" : "promo2",
          "price" : 270
        },
        {
          "code" : "promo3",
          "price" : 250
        }
      ]
```